# call product_id_change in another method odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

in model sale.order.line the is function :

```
def product_id_change(self , cr ,uid ids ........):
```

well , what I've been trying to do is trigger this function in another method like :

```
@api.multi   
def change2(self):
    self.product_id_change(self.product2)
```

but its not working ! 
i got error : method take 6 arguments (6given )
so they told me that i should pass more arguments
so i change i tried this :

```
 self.product_id_change(                                                
        self.env.user.property_product_pricelist.id,                       
        self.product_id.prod_replace.id,                                   
        qty=1,                                                            
        qty_uos=1,                                                         
        partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.id,                            
        date_order=self.order_id.date_order)
```

now i have no errors , and it execute the function but there is changes .
it really need help here !
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in order to use product_id_change !
you dont need to pass all elements ,

```
def prod_change(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):                               │
    print "new traitement-----------------======================="               │
    order_line = self.pool('sale.order.line')                                    │
    current_line = order_line.browse(cr, uid,                                    │
                                     ids[0],                                     │
                                     context=context)                            │
                                                                                 │
    print current_line.id                                                        │
    order_obj = self.pool.get('sale.order')                                      │
    order_id = order_obj.browse(cr, uid,                                         │
                                current_line.order_id.id,                        │
                                context=context)                                 │
    print order_id                                                               │
    order_lines = []                                                             │
    line_vals = self.product_id_change(                                          │
        cr, uid, 0, order_id.pricelist_id.id,                                    │
        current_line.product_id.prod_replace.id,                                 │
        partner_id=order_id.partner_id.id)['value']                              │
                                                                                 │
    line_vals.update(                                                            │
        {'product_id': current_line.product_id.prod_replace.id})                 │
    print order_lines                                                            │
    order_lines.append([1, ids[0], line_vals])                                   │
    order_obj.write(cr, uid,                                                     │
                    order_id.id,                                                 │
                    {'order_line': order_lines})                                 │
                                                                                 │
    return True
```

well , the dict return by :

```
product_id_change(                                          │
        cr, uid, 0, order_id.pricelist_id.id,                                    
        current_line.product_id.prod_replace.id,                                 
        partner_id=order_id.partner_id.id)['value']
```

we can use it to add new line or replace the same line use the correct id like in the code below :

```
order_lines.append([1, ids[0], line_vals])                                   
    order_obj.write(cr, uid,                                                     
                    order_id.id,                                                 
                    {'order_line': order_lines})
```

tds[0] gave us the current record id .
thank you guys .

Answer (score 1):

You need to give this many arguments.

```
self.product_id_change(pricelist_id,product_id,qty=qty,uom=uom_id,qty_uos=qty,uos=False,name=name,partner_id=partner_id,lang=False,update_tax=True, date_order=date_order, packaging=False, fiscal_position=fiscal_position, flag=False, context=self._context)
```

Comment: hello viki , well
i did as u said , i had to add few changes cause some arguments were missing we cant just call them like that :
self.product_id_change(pricelist_id=self.env.user.property_product_pricelist.id,product_id=self.product_id.prod_replace.id,qty=1,uom=0,qty_uos=1,uos=False,name=self.product_id.prod_replace.name,partner_id=self.order_id.partner_id.id,lang=False,update_tax=False,date_order=self.order_id.date_order,packaging=False,fiscal_position=False,flag=False,context=self._context )

Comment: and got this errors 
 and  i got this errors File "/mnt/extra-addons/product_end_life_cycle/models/order_line.py", line 47, in prod_change     context=self._context   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper     return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 592, in new_api     result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs) TypeError: product_id_change() got an unexpected keyword argument 'product_id'

Comment: Hi Mdj.
You used product_id as keyword argument. you just need to call like this..
 self.product_id_change(pricelist_id=self.env.user.property_p‌​roduct_pricelist.id,‌self.prod‌​uct_id.prod_replace.‌​id,qty=1,uom=0,qty_u‌​os=1,uos=False,name=‌​self.product_id.prod‌​_replace.name,partne‌​r_id=self.order_id.p‌​artner_id.id,lang=Fa‌​lse,update_tax=False‌​,date_order=self.ord‌​er_id.date_order,pac‌​kaging=False,fiscal_‌​position=False,flag=‌​False,context=self._‌​context )

Comment: hi , well i did that just like u mentioned ,,
my prints are showing that its calling and changing the line with the new values , but in my view still same old values

Comment: Hi, for that you need to set values in the line from resulting values from that method calling.

Comment: hi , i fond a solution ill post it =)